# Пропорциональное изменение размеров окна

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Как в winapi изменять размер окна сразу по x и y координатам (т.е., потянуть можно только за уголок окна, за правую или левую сторону нельзя)?

Comment: Даже когда тянете за уголок, можно тянуть строго горизонтально или вертикально. Т.е. менять только одну координату.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Нет такой функции у окон "из коробки". Но можно перехватить у окна [WM_SIZING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632647(v=vs.85).aspx) и кастомизировать `(RECT*)lParam` с учетом пропорций (`wParam` дает понять, за какую конкретно границу потянул пользователь).

Но я бы это делал только при какой-нить зажатой доп. клавише, типа `Ctrl`.

Comment: спасибо, сейчас буду эксперементировать

Comment: Спасибо, всё прекрасно работает